# Django: get all parent objects that contain object in manytomany field

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following User object as a simple example

```
class AppUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    follows = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='follows_users', symmetrical=False)
```

I want to get all the user's that follow a user. for example

```
u2.follows.add(u1)
u3.follows.add(u1)
```

I want to return [u2,u3] as a result for users that follow u1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `related_name` you set in the field definition:

```
users_who_follow_u1 = u1.follows_user.all()
```

You should also find a better name for it such as `followed_by`.

Comment: sorry for hijacking this question.
How would you do the opposite? If you want to see who a user is following? In other words: all "parent" AppUser

Comment: Well you just use the "field"'s name: `user.follows.all()`